# Find the derivative of the following integral

Tags: calculus

Find the derivative of $f(x)= \int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t} dt$.

My first reaction was to apply the FTOC, but I don't believe I can do this because $\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}$ is not defined at $t=0$ and thus it is not continuous in the interval of integration. I am trying to re-learn calculus after being away from it for so long and I am a bit rusty. My book doesn't give a clear solution, so any pointers on what to do in this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: After some internet digging, I've learned that what I need to solve the problem is [differetiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), which states $$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t) dt)=f(x,b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(x,a(x))\cdot a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt $$

Thus, $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t} dt)=-\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}+\int_0^x \sin(xt)dt=-\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}-\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}(1-2\cos(x^2))$

Edit 2: I'm not so sure that my above method is correct anymore.

Comment: $f(x)$ isn't well defined. The integral does not converge. (Sorry for the irritating typo in the first comment).

Comment: Although the integral itself doesn't converge, we can still solve for the derivative of the integral (see my edit for details).

Comment: blindly applying some formula won't help you. $f(x,0)$ isn't defined nor exists as a limit

Comment: notice that $\cos$ is roughly $1$ near zero. So you are basically trying to derive $\int_x^0 \frac{1}{t} \;\mathrm d t$. The integral is $-\infty$ for any $x\ne 0$. What should the derivative of $-\infty$ be?

Comment: What you are saying indeed makes sense, but I am still skeptical. I see that $\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}$ is not defined at $t=0$, which was my original concern. However both my book and wolfram alpha will give me the same answer that I derived by blindly applying the formula. I'm clearly missing a technique of integration.

Comment: user251257 is right. For more to be said, you'd need to quote the book and/or specify the Wolfram|Alpha input that appear to be giving the incorrect result.

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28+integral%28%28cos%28xt%29%29%2Ft+dt%29+from+t%3Dx+to+t%3D0%29).

Comment: well, WA thinks the derivative of $\int_x^0 1/t \; dt$ is $-1/x$...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that underneath the incorrect result, Wolfram|Alpha also says (contradicting itself) "integral does not converge".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this integral does not converge for any $x \neq 0$. This is due to the fact that
$$ \int_0^{a} \frac{1}{x} dx$$
does not converge for any $a$. So it does not make sense to talk about the derivative of the integral in your question.

We can note that if the original integral was
$$ \int_x^{1} \frac{\cos tx}{t} dt,$$
then this has a derivative that makes sense for all $x > 0$. Further, the derivative is exactly what you think the derivative should be, as indicated by the work in the OP.